# Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three points located on a circle and let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be the midpoints of the arcs $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ respectively.

Tags: geometry

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three points located on a circle and let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be the midpoints of the arcs $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ respectively. Lines $AP$, $BQ$, $CR$ intersect lines $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ in $L$, $M$, $N$ respectively. Show that
$$\frac{|AL|}{|PL|}+\frac{|BM|}{|QM|}+\frac{|CN|}{|RN|}\geqslant 9.$$
When do we have equality?

I could show that each of the small triangles have two equal sides
I tried to use powers of points but I come up with nothing much.

Comment: Have you tried applying an affine transformation to make the points $A,B,C$ the vertices of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @TedShifrin That would make the circle into an ellipse (and I'm not sure if they remain midpoints of the arcs). Does that simplify the approach?

Comment: @CalvinLin Probably not. I don't see how power of a point is remotely relevant. To the OP: Have you tried to use explicitly the fact that $P,Q,R$ are the midpoints of the arcs?

Comment: @CalvinLin Because that was all the OP mentioned having tried.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, I read that as being directed at me, since the next line then was "To the OP:".

Comment: @coco you aren't very talkative...

Comment: Here is the answer to your $2^{\rm{nd}}$ question. The equality holds when the triangle formed by the points $A$, $B$, and $C$ is an equilateral triangle. In this special case, each term on the LHS of the inequality equals 3.